# Is it impossible to call custom application handler multiple times from js simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, web-applications

I registered my [application protocol handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).
But it does not work as expected  by some reason.
If my JS code calls this application protocol handler from my web page multiple times simultaneously or in rather short intervals of time(1-5 seconds) then only one handler will be started, all others calls will be lost.
But sometimes browser starts my application protocol handler for all calls.
As I can see there is almost the same behavior in Chrome and in IE 11.
Are there any restrictions on calls to application protocol handler?